# Bulk sending files on SharePoint Online + prevent from downloading

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, modern-experience, document

There are 2 things I'm trying to wrap my head around.

1. In the SharePoint Online library, when I select a file, I have the option to "Share" on the top ribbon. As soon as I select more than one file, the functionality disappears, it is no longer available. I understand this is a normal behavior. But, is there any way to change this? How can I bulk share files from library? (I would like to select files and share them via email)
2. I have created a choice column with 2 options: Public and Confidential. Files tagged "Confidential" shouldn't be available for everyone to download freely (users should only be able to read them). I am aware SharePoint doesn't support permissions management based on metadata/categories. I was thinking about creating a folder with separate permissions - in this case, Restricted View would probably do the trick. However, this solution is far from perfect - I would say it's crude and clunky. Not very sophisticated.

These two functionalities should work together. So, I would like to be able to share multiple files at once + if I share files tagged "Confidential", the person should be able to read, but not to download.

There are probably no out of the box solutions. Do you have any ideas? I really don't know how to go about this. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct, no out of the box solutions. If you want to share multiple files, add them to single folder and then share the folder. Else, you will have to develop custom functionality on your own - preferably SPFx list view command set: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api

Comment: Hi @Lukas, does my below answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, currently there are no SharePoint out of the box solutions available for selecting more than one file and share those with other users.

Check below suggestions:

1. If you want to share multiple files, add them to single folder and then share the folder. Else, develop custom share functionality on your own using preferably SPFx list view command set. Check below links for more information:

   - [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api) - Microsoft documentation
   - [React Multishare Command Extension with PnPJs](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-command-share-pnpjs) - SPFx list view command code similar to your requirements.
     [image]
2. Your approach about creating a separate folder for Confidential files and providing "Restricted View" permissions to users to prevent downloading of files is correct SharePoint out of the box approach. You can also consider creating separate document library for confidential files if it suits your requirements.